# Как верно передавать yield и где мой первый элемент?

Tags: python, yield

Добрый день уважаемые.

Решил изучить yield и все что с ним связано. Нписал простую программку.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

def cor_line_get(mylist):
    print("cor# >")
    while True:
        print(mylist)

        for mylistline in mylist:
            new_mylist = None
            print("cor# {}".format(mylistline))
            new_mylist = (yield mylistline)

            if new_mylist:
                mylist = new_mylist
                print("cor# break")
                break
        else:
            print("cor# <")
            break

def main():
    mylist = ("1","3")
    print("main:>")
    cor_mylist = cor_line_get(mylist)

    for data in cor_mylist:
        print("main: {}".format(data))

        if data == "3":
            mylist = ("11","22","33")
            cor_mylist.send(mylist)
    print("main:<")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

В результате получаю:

```
main:>
cor# >
('1', '3')
cor# 1
main: 1
cor# 3
main: 3
cor# break
('11', '22', '33')
cor# 11
cor# 22
main: 22
cor# 33
main: 33
cor# <
main:<
```

Самое интересное что после cor# 11 идет cor# 22, а где main: 11 ?

Можете пояснить как верно передать значение что бы он заново корректно начал возвращать данные?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А к чему конструкция `new_mylist = (yield mylistline)`?

Comment: По идее мы можем послать через send новое значение и это значение будет передано new_mylist. После чего проверяется что new_mylist не равен None и происходит присвоение mylist = new_mylist и после чего мы выходим из for и заново заходим. Возможно именно вот этот выход и создания нового итератора приводит к пропуску yield. Вот тут есть об этом http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf

Comment: 11 возвращается в результате вызова `cor_mylist.send(mylist)`

Answer (score 0):

Увидеть что происходит, легко можно в дебаге, установив точки на все строки кода, и модифицировав код так:

```
if data == "3":
    mylist = ("11","22","33")
    cor_mylist.send(mylist)
continue  # добавить это
```

когда происходит вызов `cor_mylist.send(mylist)`
управление передается в `cor_line_get()` и происходит `yield mylistline = 11`.
Но в `main()` это приходится на строку `continue`, а не на строку `for data in cor_mylist:`, что ожидаете вы. Те 11 просто теряется.